# Twitter typeahead - %QUERY being passed as string for remote query

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I've looked at a number of [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983675/twitter-typeahead-remote) on here, (as well as the [official examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote)) but I can't seem to find a problem similar to my own.

I'm probably being a bit thick here - my %QUERY string is being passed as part of a remote query, which I obviously don't want. 
example:

```
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://local.example.co:8000/search-schools/%QUERY"`
```

Here's my JS (as you can see I have multiple input boxes on a page, each one on a separate bootstrap3 tab (that will be the focus of another question):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var schoolSource = new Bloodhound({
                hint: false,
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                remote: {
                   url: '/search-schools/%QUERY'
                }
            });
            schoolSource.initialize();

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

            $('#schoolSearch1').typeahead(null, {
                name: 'schoolSearch1',
                displayKey: 'name',
                source: schoolSource
            });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

            $('#schoolSearch2').typeahead(null, {
                name: 'schoolSearch2',
                displayKey: 'name',
                source: schoolSource
            });

</script>
```

**Behaviour:**
I can see that when I enter search text into the input box, an attempt to communicate with the remote URL is made, however it passes the literal %QUERY string instead of what's in the input box.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the query string to be passed to bloodhound?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the sample in the link from OP, you should probably include the `wildcard` property in your remote configuration. Try:

```
var schoolSource = new Bloodhound({
      hint: false,
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
          url: '/search-schools/%QUERY',
          wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks Amit, I think we were typing the answer simultaneously. I'll mark your response as the answer

Comment: In your answer you say you still don't understand this. Well, it's simply how the API is defined. No "default" wildcard is defined, so you need to specify the value.

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix, although I still don't understand why this parameter needs to be included. Simply change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var schoolSource = new Bloodhound({
                hint: false,
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                remote: {
                   url: '/search-schools/%QUERY'
                }
            });
            schoolSource.initialize();

</script>
```

to this (**note additional entry within remote**):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var schoolSource = new Bloodhound({
        hint: false,
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
           url: '{% url 'schoolSearchJSONResponseEmpty' %}%QUERY',
           wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });
    schoolSource.initialize();
</script>
```